# How to use "DataAnnotations" Validation without OnValidSubmit

Tags: c#, blazor

I have used "DataAnnotations" Validation in Blazor application with the help of below link.It works fine when I use "OnValidSubmit" in EditForm.I would like to know how to use DataAnnotations Validation When I click on button (without OnValidSubmit in EditForm)

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/validation-in-blazor-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to Do the Following, based on that Page:

```
<EditForm Model="@employee" EditContext="@editContextForButton">
```

And in the end of the form

```
<button onclick="@validSubmit">submitButton</button>
```

Finally you do the following in **@code**

```
private EditContext editContextForButton {get;set;}

protected override void OnTinitializedAsync(){
    editContextForButton  = new EditContext(YourModelHere);
}

private void validSubmit(){
    editContextForButton.Validate();
}
```

I Test it and it works!